# javascript function behaving differently

Tags: javascript

I have a `function` in javascript:

```js
var a=function greet(){
  console.log("Hello");
}
var b=a;
b();
```

While creating a new var b and assigning function `a` to `b` logs `hello`.However the code:

```js
function greet(){
  console.log("Hello");
}()
```

logs error.Why?
Also

```
(function greet(){
  console.log("Hello");
})()
```

and

```
var a=function greet(){
  console.log("Hello");
}()
```

logs "Hello".please explain the logic behind this.

Comment: Not sure but `function fn(){}` makes it function declaration where as `var fn = function(){}` is an assignment. So this function is treated as anonymous function and called immediately. It fails in first because you are calling  a named function whose reference is not yet added in heap

Comment: @Rajesh You might as well make this an answer. That's exactly what the problem is. :)

Comment: whats the reason for downvote?

Answer (score 1):

```
  function greet(){
    console.log("Hello");
  }()
```

There showing error because you invoked function immediately but not wrapped function body with '()'. So the invoke function immediately you should follow following pattern:

```
(fucntion(){ /* code*/ })()
```

But your first example is working because of you storing function in a variable and calling it later as a callback style.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you are assigning a function to variable a, then making b a reference to variable a. Then you are calling b which executes function a.

In your second example, you are creating a function, but you are not assigning it or calling it. If you simply call the function in your second example it will work as intended.

```js
function greet(){
console.log("Hello");
}

greet();
```

Your third example is what is known as a 'self executing function' - meaning you don't have to call it for it to execute.

<s>In your fourth example, you are assigning a function to variable a, but not executing it. The following adjustment will make example 4 work.</s>

```js
var a=function greet(){
console.log("Hello");
}

a();
```

Comment: The OP's fourth example "works" as is to log "Hello" the console, because it *does* execute the function.

Comment: @nnnnnn You're right. I can't seem to find documentation on function(){}() style syntax, can you link something? or if that isn't a method, why is fourth working?

Comment: The `function(){}` part is a function expression, the `()` invokes it immediately, and the function's return value is assigned back to the `a` variable. (Though in this case it returns `undefined` because it has no `return` statement.) Any function expression can be immediately invoked by adding `()`, and basically any time you see the keyword `function` after any operator you have a function expression and not a function statement.

Comment: @nnnnnn Is there any documentation for that that I could read? Genuinely curious about this () portion at the end.

Comment: Try Ben Alman's article on the [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

Answer (score 0):

As commented before, when you define a function expression, the function on RHS is treated as anonymous function. Reference of this function will not be registered.

**Sample:**

```js
var a = function test(){
  console.log("test");
}

test();
```

But when you declare a named function, it will be registered in heap and will retrieve its reference from there.

Now question is when is this action performed?

When ever its surrounding script is executed. i.e.

```js
function test(){
  // some code
} // when this line is evaluated, function reference will be added in heap.
```

But when you do

```js
function test(){
  console.log('test')
}()
```

when it reaches last line (`}()`), it will try to execute `test()`, but reference to this test is not defined yet and will throw error.

You may also ask why IIFE (`(function (){...})()`) works, thats is because, its surrounded by `()`. This makes it expression and outside this parenthesis, it becomes anonymous.

**Note:** As I'm not sure, making this as a community answer. Please add if anything is incorrect or missing.

---

As pointed out by @[nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn), my assumptions are incorrect. Please refer comments for more information.

Comment: The error isn't that `test` is not defined yet, it is just a syntax error that you aren't allowed to follow a function statement with `()`. That's why the error is "Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token )" and not a ReferenceError.

Comment: @nnnnnn I was not aware about this hence I mention, I'm not sure. But please edit answer as that will help others. Also if its not allowed, question would arise, *Why is it allowed for anonymous functions*

Comment: It's allowed with function expressions but not function statements. A function expression isn't necessarily anonymous.

Comment: @nnnnnn Then I guess my assumptions were incorrect and this answer would only mislead. Can you post an answer (*if and when you are free*), as this is a question many will have (*including me*) and it will help.

Comment: @nnnnnn so grouping operator needs to contain a function expression?

Comment: `var a=function greet(){
  console.log("Hello");
}` is a function expression so grouping operator works with it...Is it a right assumption?